# How to pass headers for an XMLHttpRequest request

Tags: javascript, http

I have an api which requires few headers to passed to get the response.Below is the working postman

[image]

Now Iam doing an http call to consume this and below is the code Iam using

```
 var jobendpoint = 'http://rundeck:4440/api/14/project/Demo/jobs';
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
 http.open('GET',jobendpoint,false);
    http.setRequestHeader('Accept','application/json');
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json');
    http.setRequestHeader('X-Rundeck-Auth-Token','XgTeIxQLUiv3lOSl8cXNkt4bxIGFjbzl');
 http.send();
  var joblist = http.responseText;
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && http.status == 200) {
        joblist = http.responseText;
         }
        }
        return joblist
}
```

But when I try this it is not working.I can see that headers are not properly passed.How can we pass those headers to this GET call.can someone help .

Updating error******
Im getting 403 forbiddden error since my headers are not properly set.Below is the screen shot of headers passed in network tab of firefox
[image]

Ive edited the headers directly in firefox n/w tab and sent the call and it worked.Below is the screen shot

[image]

How can I add the headers the way I had in second screen shot

Comment: How is it "not working"? Do you get an error? Unexpected result? If so, what?

Comment: what do you see in the network tab, try to do a little more inside the callback

Comment: It is giving me 403 forbidden error since my header is not getting set properly @WalleCyril

Comment: @Frxstrem  
It is giving me 403 forbidden error since my header is not getting set properly

Comment: @WalleCyril I've edited my question added the issue with scrren shots of n/w tab.can you please have a look

Comment: @Frxstrem I've edited my question added the issue with scrren shots of n/w tab.can you please have a look

Answer (score 2):

The MDN page for [`XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader) states:

> For your custom fields, you may encounter "not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response" exception when you send request to cross domain. In this situation, you need set "[Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers)" in your response header at server side.

In your case, the `X-Rundeck-Auth-Token` header is such a custom header, and therefore this header must be listed in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header from the server, otherwise you'll get an error as above and the request will fail.

`Accept`, `Accept-Language`, `Content-Type`, `Content-Length` are whitelisted headers that can be set without specifying them in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header; there's also a [list of request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) that can never be set, even if they are listed.

Comment: Then what needs be added in this case?

Comment: As my answer states, you need to send a `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header from the server, that lists your custom header (`X-Rundeck-Auth-Token`), to be able to set that header in an `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: add some code please.  just linking to some documentation is not helpful